# Angular dynamic input fields with storage

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create dynamic input fields and pushing those typed values to localstorage in AngularJS using NgStorage.

Problem is that I am not sure how to use ng-repeat in my case of scope and storage usage, so I could create new input fields.

In the end it should create/display two fields, when typed into those fields, data is saved into localstorage and when clicked "Add", it adds two new fields where to enter data, and so on. The "Delete" button should delete last two added fields.

[Example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/M6z56tpOFQHLDjMxcHYE?p=preview)

Currently for ng-repeat there is used `ng-repeat="language in storage.languages"`, but at the moment it doesn't show fields or function when clicking "Add" button.

I hope I made everything clear from my point. If there is any questions, please fire away! Thank you for you time and help!

Comment: I believe the ngStorage cares about transforming js object to key/value pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `language`, not $storage.languages in ng-model for inputs:

```
<form>
    <div class="language" ng-repeat="language in $storage.languages">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="language">Language</label>
            <input type="text" id="language" ng-model="language.name">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="skill">Skill</label>
            <input type="text" id="skill" ng-model="language.skill">
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="clearAll()">Clear data</button>
    <button ng-click="removeLanguage($index)">Delete</button>
    <button ng-click="addLanguage()">Add</button>
</form>
```

also, the `languages` field should be initially set to empty array `[]` to make `push({})` work.

Please see http://plnkr.co/edit/pHPZhgJMbEqX0mfWFnMQ?p=preview

Comment: sorry, what exactly is not working? for me it looks fine, it remembers languages i entered. Have you tried my Plunk? You might need to click "Clear data" first time because the old object could be persisted in the storage.

Comment: also, I see `$reset` clears the storage and not sets it to default values, so `clearData` method should be changed to `$localStorage.$reset({ languages: []});`

Comment: Your solution seems to work. Thank you very much, very appreaciated!

@admax Thanks, this was also needed!

Answer (score 0):

The delete function is broken. This should fix it:

```
$scope.removeLanguage = function () {
    $scope.$storage.languages.splice(this.index, 1);
}
```